# How can I validate transaction?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, contract-design

I have question related to transactions. Is is possible to verify transaction by sender and receiver. For example user A want to send money to user B. User A create transaction, digitaly signed. Miners/validator verify transaction and that mean that user A sending some money to user B. But what if user B is not willing to accept this money? Is there some way to ask user B do you want this money to accept (mybee through contract ..)?

Comment: it works like a bank, if you send money to some account, it will be registered no matter you want it or not

Comment: Is it possible for smart contracts to accept transaction (sending money) only if there is conformation from recipient? Is that revert() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `revert()` or `require(msg.value == 0)` in your fallback function for rejecting coming Ethers. But anyways somebody send Ether to you with `selfdestruct()` function. It is a way to forcefully send ether. In EOAs there is no way to rejecting coming money.